# Getting compass direction on android

Tags: android, sensors, android-sensors, device-orientation

I'm trying to make a compass app for android, as many others have before me.

However, I'm having a problem understanding how the whole rotation matrix thing is supposed to work. I've tried my way forward and have come up with the code below:

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .add(R.id.container, new PlaceholderFragment())
                    .commit();
        }
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        /*switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.action_settings:
                return true;
        }*/
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {
        TextView degreesText;
        ImageView needleView;
        private SensorManager sMan;
        private float[] mAcc = new float[3];
        private float[] mMag = new float[3];
        private float[] mRotationMatrix = new float[9];
        private float[] mOrientation = new float[3];
        private float fAzimuth;
        private boolean firstRun;

        public PlaceholderFragment() {
        }

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);

            //Test if application has been started for the first time
            firstRun = getActivity().getSharedPreferences("PREFERENCE", MODE_PRIVATE).getBoolean("firstRun", true);

            if (firstRun) {
                //Build warning dialog
                AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());

                //Set message and title
                builder.setMessage(R.string.dialog_message).setTitle(R.string.dialog_title);

                //Add dismiss button
                builder.setNeutralButton(R.string.dismiss, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        //On okay click
                    }
                });

                AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();

                //Show dialog
                dialog.show();
            }

            //Set firstRun to false, so dialog doesn't show again
            getActivity().getSharedPreferences("PREFERENCE", MODE_PRIVATE).edit().putBoolean("firstRun", false).commit();

            //Get text and image views
            degreesText = (TextView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.degrees_text);
            needleView = (ImageView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.needle);


            //Set up sensor manager
            sMan = (SensorManager)getActivity().getSystemService(SENSOR_SERVICE);

            //Listener for magnetic and accelerometer events
            SensorEventListener eventListener = new SensorEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
                    switch (event.sensor.getType()) {
                        case Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER:
                            mAcc = event.values.clone();
                            break;
                        case Sensor.TYPE_MAGNETIC_FIELD:
                            mMag = event.values.clone();
                            break;
                    }

                    SensorManager.getRotationMatrix(mRotationMatrix, null, mAcc, mMag);
                    SensorManager.getOrientation(mRotationMatrix, mOrientation);

                    fAzimuth = (float)Math.round(Math.toDegrees(mOrientation[0]));
                    fAzimuth = (fAzimuth + 360) % 360;

                    degreesText.setText(String.valueOf(fAzimuth));
                    needleView.setRotation(-fAzimuth);
                }

                @Override
                public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor sensor, int accuracy) {
                }
            };

            //Register listeners for magnetic and accelerometer sensors
            sMan.registerListener(eventListener, sMan.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_MAGNETIC_FIELD), SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);
            sMan.registerListener(eventListener, sMan.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER), SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);

            return rootView;
        }
    }
}
```

This works perfectly well as long as my phone is in portrait mode and laying down on a flat surface. My problem is in understanding what I should do to make the same thing work in both portrait and landscape mode, as well as when I hold the phone in some other orientation.

From what I've read I need to use `SensorManager.remapCoordinateSystem()`, but I don't understand which two axes I'm supposed to supply, and how it works.

Any help in understanding all of this would be greatly appreciated, thank you!